# How can I clone github in cmd?

Tags: github, cmd, clone, git-clone

Thanks for help me 
I need someone to help me in cmd I can't clone git in cmd
What do I need to do that ?

Comment: For further questions, please consider providing more information, e.g. what you have tried, and/or what the errors are

Comment: You do not want to clone github but a repository hosted at github.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of error message are you getting? it should be as simple as: `git clone [url] [folder]`

Do you have git installed on your pc? you can install git via [here](https://git-scm.com/)

What did you try till now, can you supply some more information?

Comment: Thank you . I need to install git. Any version for Windows

Comment: Could you accept this answer  as the correct one. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: This is not an answer - it's a list of questions.